# Using SST framework, how do you click a link by css class or xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am testing a website that has buttons that are not discernible by element or id. However, I am able to identify it by `xpath` or `css` class. How do you click on a button using one of those two attributes. I'm able to assert the button is there using `get_element_by_xpath;` however, I seem unable to use the `click_element`, `click_link`, or `click_button` using `id_or_elem`. What statement would you use to click on a button like this?

Edit:
The test code looks like this: (webpage name removed on purpose)

```
class TestMyTest(cases.SSTTestCase):

def test_mytestcase_home_page(self):
    go_to('http://www.mywebpage.com')
    assert_title_contains('Page Name')
    assert_element(tag='a', text='Log in')
    click_element(id_or_elem='page_nav')
    assert_title_contains('Login')
    assert_element(id='tbLUser')
    write_textfield('tbLUser','username')
    assert_element(id='tbLPass')
    write_textfield('tbLPass','badpassword')
    assert_element(css_class='btn-login1')
    get_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_box"]/div/a/img')
```

The code I'm trying to test from:

```
<div class="btn-login1">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=javascript:return Validate(document.theLoginForm,'/mypage/mywebpage.asp');" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('lg5_login','','/assets/page4/lg5_login_f2.png',1);">
<img name="lg5_login" src="http://www.mywebpage.com/login/lg5_login.png" border="0" alt="Log in Now">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the snippet of HTML and the code invoking the events in question.

Comment: Can you also paste the error you get? Just out of curiosity have you tried using `wait_for(assert_title, 'Some page title')` before performing any action on the element you are getting issue with?

Comment: `<a hre"javascript:void(0)"` That doesn't seem right...

Comment: That should be '<a href ..>', sorry about that.

Comment: When I attempt to perform the do the 'click_element(id_or_elem '...')', I receive the following error message: AssertionError: Element with id: '//*[@id="login_box"]/div/a/img' does not exist

Comment: have you tried clicking on `a` tag instead of `image`?. And as I said before use some `wait`

Comment: @Saifur, click_button, click_element, and click_link all have a built in wait that is set to True. You can see it in the way the screen moves as the test is executed. In the first click that I have, it is an id that contains two buttons, but for some reason it is assuming the first button and not the second. This issue that I have now is that while I could use <a> instead, it would then have to contend with multiple links on the page.

Comment: I am kind of confuse with code above. ` I assume click_element(id_or_elem, wait=True)` and you have to set `wait=True`. Again I am not an expert on `SST`. I assume you also should be able to pass `click_element(get_element_by_xpath('//*[@class='btn-login1']/a'), wait=true)`

Comment: @Saifur, I'm not denying your expertise, but that still produces an error. A different error, but a new error: AssertionError: Could not identify element: 0 elements found

Comment: @Brenda it's probably the xpath is not correct. Is there a way to elaborate your html more?

Comment: I wish there were a much easier way to copy and paste the exact code I'm trying to pull from. If I do what you suggested for the first cick_element (I changed it to click_button(get_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page_nav"]/div[2]/a[1]/span'),wait=True) and the other that I'm having issue with to the similar xpath, it throws the following error message: AssertionError: Element <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0397F6F0> is not one of ('submit',). I wish I could elaborate more without giving away too much proprietary information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65613/discussion-between-saifur-and-brenda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this answer is helpful to someone else. We we able to solve the issue with the following solutions.

```
click_element(get_element_by_xpath('your xpath'), wait=True)
click_link(get_element_by_xpath('your xpath'), wait=True)
click_button(get_element_by_xpath('your xpath'), wait=True)
```

[Parameters: id_or_elem](http://testutils.org/sst/actions.html#click-element) The identifier of the element, or its element object.
All of the click actions should support id or element